# Notification not occurring for added passes in Passbook

Tags: ios, xcode, passbook

I'm very simply trying to be notified when a Pass is added to a passbook.

One thing to note is that I'm also attempting to use a Pass that I generated using a different apple dev account than what my app is using.  I'm trying to figure out if that is part of the problem or not.

This is one VC in a 3-tab application.

ViewController.m:

```
@interface ViewController ()
{
    PKPassLibrary *_passLibrary;
    NSArray *_passes;
}
@end
```

"viewDidLoad":

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //init passbook
    _passLibrary = [[PKPassLibrary alloc] init];

    _passes = [_passLibrary passes];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(passLibraryDidChange:) name:PKPassLibraryDidChangeNotification object:_passLibrary];
}
```

and my notification handler:

```
- (void)passLibraryDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
      NSLog(@"%@", @"passes added");
    });
}
```

When I run the app in the iOS Simulator, all works as expected and I can see the log output to the console in Xcode.

When I run on the device, the notification is not called when the Pass is added. On the device, I can't even list any passes.

What's even more strange, is that when I go to delete the Pass from passbook, then re-enter the app, the notification will be called.

ps: I really hope it's something simple I'm missing here.

EDIT: updated with more information and a more complete code sample

Comment: In my case the only reason why that did not get called is because I  had not had `PKPassLibrary` wrapped up with `@property` (under ARC).

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be retaining a handle to your PKPassLibrary instance. Create a strong @property on your UIViewController subclass. Alloc+Init the property and configure the notification listening in the viewDidLoad (so it'll only get done once).

It might be more appropriate to set this on the UIApplication somewhere, but that depends on the app logic and how your ViewController fits into your UI (for example does it get replaced or released while you still need access to PassKit notifications?)…

Nick.

P.S. Any reason you're NSLogging on the GCD main queue so explicitly? Is that just left over from some UI feedback?

P.P.S. Seeing the notification when you re-enter the app makes perfect sense since that's when viewWillAppear will get called and a new PKPassLibrary instance will immediately fire the notification that's waiting. Not sure why it worked in the simulator - must be accidental.

Comment: thanks, i've updated with more complete code and information.  using GCD main queue as that is the recommended approach per the (very sparse) Passbook documentation from Apple.

Answer (score 0):

It came down to having the pass type identifiers created from the same source that the provisioning profile came from.

I then had to take the new Pass Certificates and add them to my keychain, then re-create the actual passes using the new pass type identifiers.

Meanwhile, In Xcode..in the summary section of my target in the Entitlements section, I can refresh the Passes and see the new pass type id's come in.

Once the app runs, I now get properly notified of any change (addition/subtraction/etc).

I also needed to make sure my _passLibrary was being properly retained.